# rendering json data in jade template

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug

we have a simple route in our express app

```
student.get('/student/:student_roll_number',function(req,res,next){
    var roll_number = req.params.student_roll_number;
    if(isNaN(roll_number))
    {
        res.sendStatus(404);
    }
    else
    {
        Stu.find({unique_roll:roll_number},function(err,data){
            res.render('student/student_details',{details:data});
        });
    }
});
```

now `details` object is being passed to jade template, but we are unable to use `details` object

if we do

```
- var name = details
```

it shows the full json string

but unable to do something like this

```
- var name = details.name
```

or

```
- var name = details["name"]
```

are we missing something, or there is better approach, as it is very simply in `php`

Comment: Is the JSON just a JSON string? Did you use `JSON.parse` on the string first?

Comment: how to go about it, we did not parse the json, would you help how to do it?

Comment: If `data` is just an unparsed JSON string, try replacing `{details:data}` with `{details: JSON.parse(data)}`. It would be useful if you could paste your Jade template as well.

Comment: Since you got more than 1 elements in the `data`, you need to parse it first like @BrendanMolloy said. Check by doing it.